# Simple examples of monoidal model categories

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

I have just learned about monoidal model categories, and I wonder what are some simple examples of them.

For example, is the category of sets an example? What about the category of vector spaces over a field?

Comment: One example is the category of non-negatively graded chain complexes of left $R$-modules for a ring $R$ given the projective model structure with monoidal action the tensor product of chain complexes. Unfortunately whether this is simple or not depends on your exposure to homological algebra.

Comment: Thanks, @Geoff. Shall I read your answer as, "No, sets and vector spaces are not examples, but a "simple" one is:"?

Comment: Haha I didn't mean it quite that way, but instead as more of a "I don't know about the others off the top of my head, but here is a class of nontrivial examples!"

Comment: nLab is your very special friend for every categorical needs: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+model+category#examples_2

Comment: Where are you having difficulties checking that the categiry of sets is an example? And with the category of vector spaces?

Comment: I have checked nlab, I was wonderin if there are any simpler ones, like the ones I mentioned. Sometimes nlab forgets those :)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Doesnt it matter which model structure I use? I do not even know if/which I should take as "customary" model structures on these categories...

Comment: If what you want is simple examples, you can keep things simple: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/trivial+model+structure

Comment: There's no serious model structure on sets or vector spaces. On sets, I think there are in fact exactly eight model structures; or something...in any case, you can try monos for cofibrations, isos for weak equivalences, epis for fibrations. This will work on sets but not generally. But this is a boring example-model categories are for homotopy theory, and all homotopy ally significant examples are more complex.

Comment: Thanks @KevinCarlson! I think the (uninteresting) model structure you described on sets works on vector spaces too. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it'll be fine there as well. The problem is with categories whose monos are not all strong, or dually for epis.